# How to divide integers and get a float in C

Tags: c, int, double, division

I'm building a paragraph difficulty labeler by getting the number of words, sentences and letters....  I'm trying to divide to integers and get a float `for example ((letter_counter / word_counter) * 100);` Dividing (80 / 21) * 100 is returning 400 instead of 380.9523, What am I doing wrong? Appreciate some help! Here is an example of my code! `letter_counter, word_counter, sentence_counter = int`

```
    // Putting all together
    float L = ((letter_counter / word_counter) * 100);
    printf("The L value = %f\n", L);

    float S = ((float) sentence_counter / word_counter) * 100;
    printf("The S value = %f\n", S);

    int index = round(0.0588 * L - 0.296 * S - 15.8);
    printf("Grade %i\n", index);

    if (index < 1)
    {
        printf("Before Grade 1\n");
    }
    else if (index >= 16)
    {
        printf("Grade 16+\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Grade %i\n", index);
    }
```

Comment: But why did you cast `sentence_counter` to `(float)` when calculating `S`?

Comment: Integer division yields an integer result - to get a floating point result, at least one of the operands must be of floating point type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put `100.00` rather than `100` to tell the compiler to evaluate the expression as a floating point expression as follows:

```
int num1 = 80;
int num2 = 21;
float L = (num1 * 100.00) / num2; // 100 -> 100.00
```

It'll result:

```
380.952393
```

Answer (score 6):

You have to cast one of the `int`s to a `float`.  For example:

```
float L = (((float)letter_counter / word_counter) * 100);
```